# How to serialize a Go map into a protobuff

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I'm following [this](https://medium.com/wtf-dial/wtf-dial-boltdb-a62af02b8955#.ubbug64d7) tutorial and got to the part on serializing/marshaling Go structs into a protocol buffer. My struct has a map and I can't find any documentation on how to handle marshaling a map.

In the following I want to serialize `Fields map[string]string`:

Go struct:

```
type Note struct {
    ID     NoteID
    Fields map[string]string
}
```

protobuf schema:

```
package internal;

message Note {
    optional int64 ID = 1;
    optional map<string, string> Fields = 2;
}
```

Go marshal:

```
func MarshalNote(n *remember.Note) ([]byte, error) {
    return proto.Marshal(&Note{
        ID: proto.Int64(int64(n.ID))
        Fields: proto.???
    })
}
```

I have no idea what to do for the last line and anything I search for talks about mapping a field to a protobuf scheme, and not about mapping a map to a protobuf scheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/gotutorial) is a well defined serialization format and one of the benefits of use it is that generates all the data structures for you(on your favorite language) just using the protobuf schema

Comment: While I tend to agree with Yandry here in that I'd also let proto create the Go stubs for me rather than trying to do it manually (that's one big point for it) I'd also be interested in doing it manually. At the end of the day the code must be there, since the automagic generation uses it, maybe based on reflection? I guess it's Star Wars time … use the source :)

Comment: there is an example here https://jacobmartins.com/2016/05/24/practical-golang-using-protobuffs/ you can check the generated code

Comment: For a map named children with key and value of type string, the generated tags look like this: `protobuf:"bytes,1,rep,name=children" json:"children,omitempty" protobuf_key:"bytes,1,opt,name=key" protobuf_val:"bytes,2,opt,name=value"`.

Comment: Ah, thanks. The example I was following for some reason does a manual marshal and unmarshal. I'll be able to test this out tomorrow.

What's the semantic difference between protocol buffer and protobuf? The page you linked me to says protocol buffer all over it.

Comment: Ops my bad I thought you were referring to a generic protocol buffer after read _a protocol buffer_, but yes Protocol Buffer == protobuf :)